# Change device time with cordova

Tags: android, cordova

is there any way to change an android device time from a cordova app?
I need to sync the device time with a server.
The app gets the server time from a webapi and if it's different from the device time i'd like to change the device time.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to bend the whole device just to make your app work. What if the server-time is wrong? What if the user wants a different time?

We have the same needs for our app, and what we are doing is to **run the app in server-time**.

*This is native Android in Java, but I think the idea should be clear and should also be possible in Cordova.*

So we have this `ServerTime` class, and whenever we need the current time in our app, we do not use <del>`new Date()`</del> or <del>`System.currentTimeMillis()`</del>, but instead use `ServerTime.now()`.

The class looks something like this (written from memory and simplified, make sure to test, maybe the diff-calculations should be + instead of - ...):

```
public static class ServerTime {

    private static long diffMillis;

    public static Date now() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - diffMillis;
        return new Date(millis;
    }

    public static void update(long serverTimeMillis) {
        diffMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - serverTimeMillis;
    }
 }
```

The server provides the server's time with every response and additionally we poll the server-time every 15 minutes or so. Whenever we get the server's time, we call `ServerTime.update(server's time in millis)`.

Comment: In Cordova this could be done in the Javascript layer of the Webview - would work equally well on iOS then too